# Analog 4-20 mA output module for process control

Tags: control-system, pid-controller

I am reading a [spec sheet](http://www.opto22.com/site/pr_details.aspx?cid=4&item=SNAP-AOVA-8) for an 8-channel analog output module for process control that says this:

> Because all current is sourced from within the module using the 24 VDC
> excitation, current outputs cannot be used with an external loop
> supply.  Current outputs are self-sourcing and cannot be used in loops
> that are loop-powered or already have a self-sourcing device in the
> loop.

I'm having a hard time interpreting this warning. This is how I understand a typical 4-20 mA control loop:

[image]

In my case the transmitter/sensor 4-20 mA input goes to an input module, gets acted upon by, say, a PID algorithm coded into the "brain" module and the output 4-20 mA ought to come out via the output module to then drive some valve/actuator.

So what's an "external loop supply"? Or a "loops that are loop-powered or already have a self-sourcing device in the loop"?

Answer (score 2):

What Opto are saying is that the output of the sender is a 20 mA loop ....BUT...... It has an internal 24 VDC power source in the module.
These senders are used in single sensor loops, and by being internally powered they reduce your need for an external loop power supply. You cannot connect two of these sensor loops in series.

Read the datasheet for the device: http://www.opto22.com/site/documents/doc_drilldown.aspx?aid=1709

Notice the difference in specification of the SNAP-AOA-3 which is both optically and transformer coupled output isolation, and does not supply loop current (so multiple sensors can be connected in series and it needs an external power supply) and the  SNAP-AOVA-8 which has an internal supply for the loop current.
You will also note that the analog voltage outputs of the  SNAP-AOVA-8 are all referenced to the same common....they are not individually isolated.

Comment: Thanks! But I assumed all control loops were axiomatically  single sensor loops. What's a multi sensor loop? How can two sensors send outputs simultanously on a 4-20 mA loop?

Comment: I've seen many industrial configurations where sensors are put in series to provide both failure capability (usually switched off by a simple knife connector) and manual versus computer control.

Answer (score 0):

Some instruments supply their own loop power (sourcing), some need loop power supplied to them (sinking).

If you have any instruments in the system that supply their own power, just switch the setting to sinking, or whatever is not sourcing 24 V.